# Tengo este código de Java para consultas a bases de datos. Pero no hace lo que debe

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Este es el código

```
private void button_registrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    try {
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/info_usuarios", "root", "");
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("insert into info_usuarios values(?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(1, "0");
        pst.setString(2, user_txtfield.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(3, password_txtfield.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        
        user_txtfield.setText("");
        password_txtfield.setText("");
        label_estado.setText(("Registro exitoso"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
    }
}
```

Estoy frustrado porque la verdad no encuentro el error. Lo que debería hacer es un registro a una bd que tengo creada, sin embargo no crea ningún nuevo registro. Agradecería un montón si alguien me explicara. Gracias de antemano.

Base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la vista de los componentes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se que hace executeupdate... pero estas haciendo un insert...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola siguiendo tu ejemplo puede hacer lo siguiente:

Asegúrate de tener el controlador JDBC de MySQL en tu proyecto. En mi caso uso maven, tienes que tener la dependencia instalada para conectarte a MySql uso un archivo pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.26</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Ahora viene la conexión a la db y la implementación para persistir contra la base de datos.

puedes utilizar una estructura de `try-with-resources` para asegurarte de que se cierre la conexión automáticamente después de usarla

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stackOverflow";
    String usuario = "root";
    String contrasena = "xxx";

    String consulta = "INSERT INTO info_usuarios (nombre, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contrasena);
         PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(consulta)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, "Miguel");
        pstmt.setString(2, "789");
        int filasAfectadas = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("filasAfectadas = " + filasAfectadas);
    } catch (SQLException e){
        System.err.println("Error al ejecutar la consulta: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Mostrando filas afectadas

```
filasAfectadas = 1
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda, saludos...